# nesting an object inside an object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Looking for some tips on how to nest objects inside objects using a form. My form currently changes the key and value of an object. However, I'm now wanting a second button to  be able to create a child (correct termanology?)form input. below you can see an example. I've spent the morning  looking at props but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to go, any suggestions are greatly appriciated

```
   {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
```

```
<form id="app">
          <h1>
            Title goes here
          </h1>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button type="button" v-on:click="addNewObject" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                (Add +) Parent
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 text_info">
              Click 'Add +' to add an object
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-for="(object, index) in objects">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="removeObject(index)" class="btn btn-rem btn-block btn-danger">
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="addNewChildObject()" class="btn btn-rem btn-block btn-success btn-suc">
                    add { }
                  </button>
              </div>


             
              <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                <div class="test">
                  <select v-model="object.type" class="selectBox classic">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Datatype</option>
                    <option v-for="type in types"> {{ type }}</option>
                  </select>
      
                  <input v-model="object.name" :name="'objects[' + index + '][name]'" type="string" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter key">
      
                  <input v-model="object.dataValue" :name="'objects[' + index + '][dataValue]'" type="string" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <pre v-if="seen">{{ mappedObjects }}</pre>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-primary" v-on:click="seen = !seen">{{ seen ? 'Click to Hide the JSON' : 'Click to Show the JSON' }}</button>
        </form>
```

```
const getDefaultObject = () => ({
    name: '',
    dataValue: '',
    type: ''
  })
  
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
      mappedObjects() {
        return this.objects.map(({
          name,
          dataValue,
          type
        }) => ({
          [name]: dataValue,
          type
        }))
      }
    },
    props: {
        
    },
    data() {
      return {
        seen: false,
        types: ['string', 'character', 'number', 'int', 'floating-point', 'boolean', 'date;'],
        objects: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addNewObject: function() {
        this.objects.push(getDefaultObject())
      },
      removeObject: function(index) {
        Vue.delete(this.objects, index);
      },
      addNewChildObject: function () {
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want n forms with n children just create a model for it following that same structure and pass props to the form.

```
    parent = {
        ...props,
        children: []
    }

    child = {
        ...props
    }
```

If the forms are too complex (or a little complex really), split them in separate components and pass children as props.

If you want to use the same form both in parent and children take a look at slots, they will allow you to create flexible layouts.